# How to connect my work laptop to my home computer

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo T500 series work laptop-Windows 7, and an emachine home computer-Windows XP. I want to use my home computer as a monitor(second screen) when working at home. I am using Verizon's dial up service.

Additionally, if this is possible can I easily revert back so family members can use the home computer when I am not using it as a second screen?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Um, did you miss out in typing the full question ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to be using the laptop's resources on the second monitor, you could probably do this with a simple VGA cable. If you don't want to be disconnecting the monitor from the desktop all the time, you could look into a cheap 2-port KVM switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of software programs that allow you to do this -- [MaxiVista](http://ttp://www.maxivista.com/) and [Extramon](http://ttp://www.extramon.com/).  They share the monitor of another computer over the network.  (Note - even if you are accessing the Internet over dialup, you can still create a local LAN between your two computers using a cross-over cable.)

Answer (score 0):

If you home computer is a desktop.  You may be able to connect connect the monitor to the laptop and have Windows extend the laptop to the second monitor.  In addition, if the home monitor has multiple inputs, you may be able to use DVI to connect your home computer via DVI and have the work laptop connect via VGA and then you could flip between the two computers by changing the monitor input.

I have two desktops connected to one monitor via to two input method.